# View function, modify node label in Matlab

Tags: matlab, treeview

I'm trying to truncate the values printed as thresholds for each node in classification tree with Matlab R2014a on Linux.

I used the `view()` function to print the tree that was obtained from `classregtree()` function.

I have 59 nodes all of them with threshold with up to 6 decimals... Hard to read and I'd like to truncate them

```
(like fprintf('%.2g')).
```

Is there a way to do so? With GUI it does not seem so.

Ps: I cannot share my data, I'm sorry

Comment: I am looking for a solution a bit more elegant than modifying the file by hand.

A work around could be to save the figure in `file1.eps` and then modify it like:
     `cat file1.eps | sed -re 's/([0-9e]+\.[0-9]{2})([0-9]*)/\1/g' > file2.eps`
But I think that a better solution could be found

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an option to set this directly.

You can use [findall](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) to grab handles to all 'Text' objects, loop over them, `get` the 'String' property, modify it to preference if it contains a long decimal number, `set` it back.

Or dig into which set of code it is that draws the tree originally, and edit that/create your own shadowing version. I think it may be the `drawtree` function in `TreeDrawer.m`, which does appear (lines 316~337ish in my version) to be using `sprintf` with `%g` to produce the text.